# How to open Linux `.so` file in Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, .so

My Linux `.so` file can be opened with the `fopen()` command in Ubuntu, but when I tried to open the file with the `fopen()` command in Mac OS X 10.6, it failed.

The error was the file type was not recognized. How can I make a Linux library or tool work on Mac OS X 10.6 without recompilation?

Comment: MacOS knows nothing about how to open Ubuntu shared object files... you would probably need to install Ubuntu in place of MacOS X, [or maybe dual boot?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromMacOSX)

Comment: yes,is dlopen().Linux binaries are completely different than Mac OS X ones,so i need recompilation,not other ways.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Linux binaries are completely different to Mac OS X ones, even on the same architecture. For starters, Linux binaries use the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format, whilst Mac OS X ones are based on the [Mach-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) format. But even if the formats were the same, the operating system interface is not the same.

As a result, Mac OS X cannot run Linux binaries directly. The safest approach would be to install Linux in a virtual machine, e.g. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org). You would then have a full-blown Linux system to do anything that you want, including accessing files on the Mac OS X host via shared folders.